# Searching in a map: Member vs. non-member lower_bound

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I need to look up two elements in a `std::map`. Since my map is sparse, I might not have an entry for every key, so I use `lower_bound` for lookup. For sake of simplicity, let's assume that I can always find two elements like this and that they are always distinct.

The quickest solution would of course be:

```
auto it1 = my_map.lower_bound(k1);
auto it2 = my_map.lower_bound(k2);
```

However, I know that the element at index `k2` is located between `begin` and the element at index `k1`. Therefore, I was thinking of using `std::lower_bound` for the second lookup to avoid having to search the full range again:

```
auto it1 = my_map.lower_bound(k1);
auto it2 = std::lower_bound(begin(my_map), it1, k2);
```

Any opinions on the second solution? Complexity-wise it should be better, but it's a lot less pleasant to look at than the original code and I'm wondering whether it is worth bothering at all. Also, should I expect any drawbacks due to the fact that I'm using the non-member `lower_bound` for the second call?

Comment: Actually complexity-wise it should be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary drawback is that the non-member `std::lower_bound` has to rely on the bidirectional iterators that `map` provides.  So while it's able to perform O(log(n)) comparisons, it still has to perform O(n) iterations.

On the other hand, the member `lower_bound()` is aware of the internal structure of the map, which is typically some sort of binary tree.  This means that's capable of traversing in ways the standard algorithm cannot.

Comment: Of course. I had the feeling that something did not add up, but I did not think of the iterator requirements. Thanks a bunch!